# Laravel TypiCMS redirects to root

Tags: laravel

I am using TypiCMS Laravel here : github.com/TypiCMS/Base and I am facing the following problem:

I created a new module named "News" by executing command: composer require typicms/news. I also added providers in config/app.php, have publish views and migrations and migrated the database too.

The only problem I am facing is that whenever the url I given, it redirects me to the root directory of my project, that is, http://localhost/mywebsite/public/

Even, if I give invalid route like localhost/mywebsite/public/foobar, instead of showing me error, it again redirects to the root directory.

I have checked the .htaccess and routes.php file and there is not modifications.

Regards:
Adnan

Answer (score 0):

TypiCMS cannot be installed in a subfolder, the root of your site must be http://localhost.